# Nokogiri xpath query results in String instead of NodeSet

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have a Nokogiri node which I'm doing an xpath query on which should return a NodeSet. Instead it returns a String.  I checked the xml source and found that the data only contains one element instead of many.

**Shouldn't it return a NodeSet with only one value, instead of a String?  How do I deal with this?**

Here's the *pseudo* xml which correctly returns a NodeSet with 2 entries:

```
<root>
    <products>
        <product>
            <productID>1</productID>
        </product>
        <product>
            <productID>2</productID>
        </product>
    </product>
</root>
```

Here's the *pseudo* xpath query:

```
//root/products/product
```

If the xml only contains one product, I get a String instead of a NodeSet with 1 entry

```
<root>
    <products>
        <product>
            <productID>1</productID>
        </product>
    </product>
</root>
```

**Update 6/12/2012:** I still believe this is a bug in Nokogiri.The above pseudo xml does not reproduce the condition, however I have several xml examples from a client which do reproduce the issue.  I could probably post an obfuscated version of the xml.  In any case I have changed the code to use [XmlSimple](http://xml-simple.rubyforge.org/) instead of Nokogiri.

Comment: That depends on your XPath, but there's no way we can tell if you don't post it.

Comment: I updated it with the _pseudo_ xml and xpath query.

Comment: Why *pseudo*? If the provided XML document isn't the actual one how can you expect people to help?

Comment: Come on! Does it really matter? I've kept the structure the same and only renamed the elements to protected the source of the data.

Comment: What is the method you are calling? `xpath`?

Comment: Please show your code. It's hard to debug code without seeing the code.

Comment: I'd say there's something wrong with your _actual_ XPath query.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = "<root><products>
  <product><productID>1</productID></products>
</product></root>"

p Nokogiri.XML(xml).xpath('//root/products/product').class,
  #=> Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet

  Nokogiri::VERSION,
  #=> "1.5.2"

  RUBY_DESCRIPTION
  #=> "ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]"
```

Either your version of Nokogiri is bad (leaning on a bad libxml2 version, likely), or your code is sufficiently different that you need to provide us with a way to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I'm running Nokogiri "1.5.3.rc5" on Ruby "ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]". Will investigate further...

Comment: @Edward See [this link](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/wiki/what-to-do-if-libxml2-is-being-a-jerk) to ensure that your libxml2 is recent-ish.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this "issue" as well, but after a bit of head scratching, I found out what I was doing wrong... I was trying to debug the xpath by printing out the results as in

```
product_element = Nokogiri.XML(xml).xpath('//root/products/product')
print "product_element is - #{product_element}\n"
```

that prints out the string version of the element, but instead when I used

```
product_element = Nokogiri.XML(xml).xpath('//root/products/product')
p product_element
```

that correctly showed it as a NodeSet.

... This may not be what was happening to you, but

Comment: No unfortunately this is not my case